# Why Was Terah Travelling to Canaan?

Tags: genesis, abraham, canaan

Genesis 11:31 states: וַיִּקַּ֨ח תֶּ֜רַח אֶת־אַבְרָ֣ם בְּנ֗וֹ וְאֶת־ל֤וֹט בֶּן־הָרָן֙ בֶּן־בְּנ֔וֹ וְאֵת֙ שָׂרַ֣י כַּלָּת֔וֹ אֵ֖שֶׁת אַבְרָ֣ם בְּנ֑וֹ וַיֵּצְא֨וּ אִתָּ֜ם מֵא֣וּר כַּשְׂדִּ֗ים לָלֶ֙כֶת֙ אַ֣רְצָה כְּנַ֔עַן וַיָּבֹ֥אוּ עַד־חָרָ֖ן וַיֵּ֥שְׁבוּ שָֽׁם׃: "And Terah took Abram his son, and Lot the son of Haran his grandson, and Sarai his daughter-in-law the wife of Abram his son; and they left together from Ur Kasdim to travel to the land of Canaan and they came until Charan and they dwelled there."

My question is why was Terah heading towards Canaan? There had not yet been any commandment for Abram to go to Canaan and Canaan was not yet the "holy land." Nor was Canaan their home country or a place where they had relatives.

It seems unlikely that Terah's intent to travel to Canaan is just a coincidence. Presumably there is some connection to Abram travelling there later on but I cannot figure out what that connection is from the text.

Does anyone have any explanation for why Terah was travelling to Canaan?

Comment: All of the people listed in the table of nations travelled to new lands and founded new cities. Thats the whole point. https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/tok/images/f/f0/Table_of_Nations2.png/revision/latest?cb=20210812084425

Answer (score 2):

### Answer based on the text

There's no motive given or hinted at in the text or elsewhere, so I'm afraid the only answer I can perceive is 'no' - there is no way to explain Terach's attempt to travel to Canaan based on the text.

### Other Thoughts

As pointed out by Abu in the comments to his answer, Canaan was the heart of the 'fertile crescent' linking Eurasia with Africa, and so it's a very natural trading link. For somebody such as Terach who was relocating for any number of reasons, Canaan would be one of the most natural directions to move - it wasn't a known region to their family, but it was still a highly 'significant' area for the ancient world. It's no co-incidence that when Abram moves there he encounters ten or more kings already settled in the region (Genesis 14).

Answer (score 2):

The text intends to show that the Israelites have a respectable and reputable lineage, because they become after all, Egyptian slaves for nearly 400 years, which is not something you would want your mother to know about.

So the text presents Abram as a direct descendant of Noah's righteous son Shem, through Arpachshad and Serug to another well-known and respected figure of the ancient world, Terah.

Now the problem is that Terah was known have lived in Ur Casdim, far to the east of the Promised Land. So we somehow have to move him west.

The connection is Deut 26:5 that presents Terah and his descendants as nomads. This is an important, in order to show that such respected figures could also be nomads, who don't usually get much respect from people living in agricultural settlements, and the Patriarchs were of course nomads to begin with. The nomadic assertion is in fact made even earlier, in Gen 9:27 which presents that Shem a tent dweller. (Other references to nomadic righteousness are to Jethro the Kenite in Exodus 18, Rahab in Joshua 2, Johonadab in II Kings 10:15-16, and Jaazaniah in Jeremiah 35.)

So we don't really need to ask the question. Of course Terah travelled to Canaan, that was the Fertile Crescent trade route and that's what nomads did.

Terah stops in Haran, in order to associate him with Laban, another descendant of Shem, and from there Abram moves further south to Canaan.

Comment: Just a few problems: 1) Deut 26:5 is in reference to Jacob/Israel, not Terah (he went down into Egypt and came out populous). 2) Ur of the Chaldeans is given as the place of Haran's birth and death, and inbetween those times he had at least two children, so you have the family remaining in Ur for at least 15 years, probably much longer. 3) If Abraham was already a Nomad, then his 'call' in Genesis 12 is nonsense - "Go from **your country** and **your kindred** and **your father's house** to the land that I will show you." Again, the text neither tells us why Terah left nor why he stayed.

Comment: The language of the masoretic text of Deut 26:5 is "my father". This isn't necessarily a specific ref only to Jaacob. It is a general ref to patrimony as shown by the intent that every pilgrim in every generation should make the declaration. A long stay in a single place does not negate nomadic ethnic identification as we know from such groups as the Roma today. Abraham's call is exactly the call of nomad, similar to the when God calls the Israelites in the desert to pull up stakes and move, although they are already nomadic. Terach moved from place to place because that was his way of life.

Comment: Dt 26:5 doesn't just say "my father" was a wandering Aramean though, it also says he went down into Egypt and became a great nation, which makes it an obvious reference to Jacob. There's no scriptural evidence that Terach actually moved more than once in his life: so it's okay if you want to declare these things as part of a tradition, but I'm not seeing an exegetical case for your claims. Abraham's call is not the call of a nomad, it was a call to "leave your country/kindred/father's house" and go to a specific land. That's not a nomadic call, that's a one-time migration.

Comment: My interpretation and method follows that of Yair Zakovitz and the Tel Aviv school regarding Gen 9:27 and Deut 26:5 as being part of the polemic between settled agriculture and nomadic culture in early Israelite thinking. There is no need to find evidence of more than one movement for Terach because the identification through Shem has already been made. Terach's movement to Haran is just a mechanism to associate him with Laban and the Aramean ancestry. It is made plausible by the type of person that the text asserts he was. Terach was also an idol worshiper, so God has to get Abraham out.

Comment: Okay, on those grounds your interpretation is fair, and you are absolutely entitled to maintain your traditional interpretation of the text. Personally I still don't think we should draw conclusions from a single verse which says somebody will dwell in the tents of Shem, nor take from one move that Terah or Abram were from nomadic peoples. The text doesn't teach it explicitly, and so I maintain that there isn't a clear answer from hermeneutics alone.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim I don't think this really answers the question. Why would the verse mention an intent to go Canaan if it was just discussing nomadic life? Just write that he moved on from Ur to Charan (I put in the "c" to distinguish from Terach's son Haran).  I also have a hard time believing that Canaan is just coincidental (i.e. that's how nomads roll) and Terach's stated intent to travel there isn't connected to the theological significance of the land in the rest of the Torah.

Comment: @conceptualinertia Canaan is not coincidental. It is on the expected trade route between Ur and Egypt, and it is the land of a subservient to Shem. My claim is that the OP question is not a question any more than the questions of why Assyria is to the east, why Lebanon is to the north and why the sea is to the west. The fact of Terach's movement is presented to provide the answer to how he could be related to the Israelite family in the land of Canaan.

Answer (score -2):

Very simple. They were never in Sumer. Ur refers to Urfa north of Haran. It will never make any sense if you believe Abraham was from Ur III. This is a tired old belief that was

Abram was semetic and he lived in the land of the Semitics which was Aram. The ancient cities all bear the names of Abraham's family. Naḫur (Til-Naḫiri), mentioned in the Cappadocian tablets (1800-1750). Harran named after Haran. This was how all ancient cities were named at the beginning of the dispersal after the flood and these cities are all in northern Aram.

Do you really think they would have cities named after them and just get up and move to a foreign land for no reason at all? That's not how the ancient world worked, especially so close to the patriarchs when God commanded people to spread out, and separated them by nation by language by family. It's an insult to think Tereh and Abram ended up in Summer.

Also "Ur of the Chaldeans" did not exist until the 9th century BC, long after Genesis was written. There is not one single good reason why Abraham was from Ur in Sumer, but there are dozens of reasons he was from Aram, in the land of Shinar. (al-Jazira).

The association of Ur Kasdim with Muqayyar, Sumerian Urim, mostly stems from the excavations carried out by the British Museum in ther late 19th and early 20th centuries, in particular the archeologist Leonard Wooley, but rests on no hard evidence.

God bless.

Comment: This doesn't answer why Terach was heading towards Canaan. Canaan wasn't the land of the Semitics.

Comment: Haran and Harran are entirely unrelated in the Hebrew. The difference in the initial sounds is obscured by our Latin alphabet, but it would be like finding a gorge and wondering if it was named after King George.